# Local Git cannot resolve hostname with "ssh://" in the config, and asking for password without

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I'm struggled with my new Gitlab server (version `12.10.3`) and my local git project: I am trying to import it, however I'm stuck with the remote URL settings.

With the following URL, git asks me a password:

```
git remote set-url origin git@192.168.1.20:mygroup/data/myproject.git
git push --all
git@192.168.1.20's password:
```

To avoid that, I've red in a different topic that I need to add `ssh://` at the beginning of the URL to make this working, and then:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@192.168.1.20:mygroup/data/myproject.git
git push --all
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.1.20:mygroup: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Of course, the IP address is reachable when I do a `ping` from my workstation. I've also setup my SSH key, added it to my Gitlab account, and added the gitlab's public key in the `known_hosts` folder:

```
ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.20 >> /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Did I missed something?

**EDIT**

Looks like there is potentially an issue with my SSH key. I've tried to debug it with `ssh -Tvvv git@192.168.1.20`, and I've got the following output:

```
[...]
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/MyName.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:+W7oskD00BfECMDiA0jTGA4pQbxeNT3v2OFrULoJ7ts
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:+W7oskD00BfECMDiA0jTGA4pQbxeNT3v2OFrULoJ7ts
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@192.168.1.20's password:
```

It seems it used the certificate authentication process. My key in `/c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_rsa` has been used to authenticate, but for some hidden reason, it didn't worked.

I've checked again on Gitlab `SSH keys` section, and the key is exactly the same as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git remote set-url origin git@192.168.1.20:mygroup/data/myproject.git
git push --all
git@192.168.1.20's password:
```

> I've also setup my SSH key

Well, looks like you didn't. To verify it start debugging with `ssh -Tv git@192.168.1.20`.

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@192.168.1.20:mygroup/data/myproject.git
```

The correct SSH URL syntax is `ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/`. See the different syntax in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_git_urls).

In your case the URL should be `ssh://git@192.168.1.20/mygroup/data/myproject.git`. The path isn't separated with `:`, it's started with `/`. A colon is used to separate `host` from the path only in scp-like syntax `[user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/`.

Comment: Still asking for a password, I've updated my question with the output of `ssh -Tvvv git@192.168.1.20` command. Looks like the SSH key process is somewhere skipped after being used.

Comment: @toshiro92 It seems Gitlab doesn't accept your key. Try to re-upload `C:\Users\MyName\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` to your account in Gitlab.

Comment: I've tried, however Gitlab says "Fingerprint has already been taken". I've also deleted it, re-added it in the GUI, and restarted Gitlab: Nothing...

Comment: I've switched to the HTTPS method instead, and it worked like a charm: I didn't find the issue behind the SSH behavior...